# Load javascript file on wopiframe.aspx in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, office-365, master-page, wopi

Is there a different way to load external javascript files on the WopiFrame.aspx / Word Online / Excel Online page?

We are using SharePoint Online. I have some external javascript files load with our masterpage. Those javascript files used to load on our WopiFrame.aspx pages too, but recently stopped. From what I can tell, sometime this month SharePoint Online changed the way some of its own javascript functions. In that change, they aren't including the js files from my masterpage on the word/excel online pages anymore.

This code is near the end of the masterpage. Would loading these files differently on the masterpage make them load on WopiFrame.aspx? Is there a different approach to get them on WopiFrame.aspx?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"><' + '/script>' + 
    '<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/js/custom-global.js"><' + '/script>' + 
    '<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/js/custom-collection1.js"><' + '/script>');
</script>
```

Comment: If you found the solution, please share it.

Comment: Never found a solution